# How to call .env {{ env('APP_NAME} }} to laravel blade template?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I tried to call APP_NAME from .env Laravel to Blade Template, but it always returned this code
`<?php echo e(env('APP_NAME')); ?>`

Master Blade `master.blade.php`

```
<title>@yield('project_title')</title>
```

Body Blade `body.blade.php`

```
@extends('master')

@section('project_title', "{{ env('APP_NAME') }}")
```

I was tried to use this :

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
composer dump-autoload
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
```

but still give me the same return.

Comment: If using an environment variable as the title why not use `{{ env('APP_NAME') }}` directly in `master.blade.php`?

Comment: I also want to use `{{ env('APP_NAME') }}` inside another section in `body.blade.php`.

Comment: You can also use the same tag in `body.blade.php`. There is no penalty on using it more than once :)

Comment: using `{{ env('APP_NAME') }}` in `master.blade.php` is working well, but in `@section ('project_title', "{{ env('APP_NAME') }})` returned as echo.

Comment: My suggestion is to skip using the `@section` and `@yield` altogether. Simply use `<title>{{ env('APP_NAME') }}</title>` in `mater.blade.php`. Makes sense?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact you should never use `env` helper directly in your application. All env should be put into config file and you should use config instead to avoid problems when config files are cached.

`APP_NAME` env is put into config file by default (see https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/app.php#L16 ) so in your Blade file you should use:

```
@section('project_title', config('app.name'))
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try to use like this May it help you

```
{{ env('MAIL_USERNAME')}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `env()` helper directly like this. `{{ }}` in blade is equivalent to `echo` in raw PHP. As you are passing an argument, not echoing something directly, you need to do it like this:

```
@section('project_title', env('APP_NAME'))
```

But generally, I don't like to use `env()` helper directly. You should be using `config()` helper. `.env` values are used by files and if you are going to use a settings package later to override the default settings and use dynamic settings from the database for example, still your app will not break. My suggestion use is:

```
@section('project_title', config('app.name'))
```

This will get the value of `app_name` key from config array from `app/config/app.php` file if you not set `APP_NAME` from `.env`.

Answer (score -1):

Try like this will help to you.

```
@php $title = env('APP_NAME'); @endphp
@section('project_title', $title)
```

Or directly you can use **env('APP_NAME')**

```
 @section('project_title', env('APP_NAME'))
```

Comment: Hi, your code is working but do you have another best practices ?